# Running a dedicated SQL Server VM in windows Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I've read that you can pay a per hour fee to license SQL Server on a Windows Azure VM, if you want to run a dedicated instance (as opposed to using Azure SQL). However, when I go to create a VM running SQL Server, only the evaluation edition is available in the image gallery. I don't see any options in the VM creation process to add the additional per hour license for SQL Server. Where does this come in to play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of Virtual Machines on Windows Azure being still in preview.
As far as I know - whilst in preview only the evaluation copy of SQL is formally available and at no extra charge. I suspect this will change when IaaS goes GA.

You can read about it [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-3)

Comment: That explains it. I didn't see the bit about full SQL not being available until the GA release of VMs.